# react-marked: dangerouslySetInnerHTML cannot read property h1 of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a markdown app using React.

Here is the JSX code for it

```js
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import marked from 'react-marked';

class App extends Component {
 
 constructor(){
  super();

  this.state = {
   input: '# Heading\n\n## Sub-heading\n\n### Another deeper heading\n\nText attributes _italic_, *italic*, __bold__, **bold**, `monospace`.\n\nHorizontal rule:\n\n---\n\nBullet list:\n* apples\n* oranges\n* pears\n\nNumbered list:\n1. apples\n2. oranges\n3. pears\n\nA [link](http://example.com).'
  }
 }

 onInputChange(event){
  let currinput = event.target.value;
  this.setState({input: currinput})
 }

 MarkIt(){
  // let output = marked(this.state.input, {sanitize: true}) ;
  return { __html: marked(this.state.input, {sanitize: true})};
 }

 render(){
 return (
   <div>
    <textarea 
     value = {this.state.input}
     onChange = {this.onInputChange.bind(this)}
     >
    </textarea>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.MarkIt()}>
     
    </div>
  </div>);
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.querySelector("#container"));
```

I am not able to figure out why it is giving cannot read propery 'h1' of undefined error on execution.

I've looked into official react docs provided by facebook but still I haven't figured out the exact reason behind this error.

Answer (score 0):

That's because react-marked returns the React node, not the HTML as it's handled in the 'Minimal usage:' section in the readme.

Good news though! You can just use like this:

```
MarkIt() {
    return marked(this.state.input, {sanitize: true});
}

...
<div>
    {this.MarkIt()}
</div>
```

Comment: This is still giving the same error. I agree with you about the return of a react node.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to use marked library instead of react-marked